# Why System.Net.Mail.MailAddress constructor parses email with slash "/" in domain part?

Tags: c#, .net, email-validation

We have following code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var mailAddress = new MailAddress("username@domain/domain.com");    // Doesn't throw FormatException
        Console.WriteLine(mailAddress.Host);                                // Prints "domain/domain.com"
    }
}
```

We expect MailAddress constructor to throw FormatException because "/" is not supported in domain name.
Is there reason why MailAddress parses them?

Comment: The MailAddress c'tor does not promise to do a full validation - ans it does not (see https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressParser.cs).

Comment: @KlausGütter
Why there is following comment on MailAddressParser class?
"This class is responsible for parsing E-mail addresses as described in RFC 2822."

Comment: It says "Parsing", not "Validating".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET uses **RFC 2822** standart for its validation process of e-mail addresses.

According to document **forward slash** (**/**) is a valid character for domain part.

Please see **address specification** at [RFC 2822 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1):

```
addr-spec       =       local-part "@" domain

local-part      =       dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part

domain          =       dot-atom / domain-literal / obs-domain

domain-literal  =       [CFWS] "[" *([FWS] dcontent) [FWS] "]" [CFWS]

dcontent        =       dtext / quoted-pair

dtext           =       NO-WS-CTL /     ; Non white space controls

                        %d33-90 /       ; The rest of the US-ASCII
                        %d94-126        ;  characters not including "[",
                                        ;  "]", or "\"
```

Domain can be **dot-atom** which is described at [RFC 2822 3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.2.4):

```
atext           =       ALPHA / DIGIT / ; Any character except controls,
                        "!" / "#" /     ;  SP, and specials.
                        "$" / "%" /     ;  Used for atoms
                        "&" / "'" /
                        "*" / "+" /
                        "-" / "/" /
                        "=" / "?" /
                        "^" / "_" /
                        "`" / "{" /
                        "|" / "}" /
                        "~"

atom            =       [CFWS] 1*atext [CFWS]

dot-atom        =       [CFWS] dot-atom-text [CFWS]

dot-atom-text   =       1*atext *("." 1*atext)
```